# How to fix error after a release-update to Ubuntu 12.10?

Tags: 12.10, upgrade, python, intel, apport

I have freshly reinstalled 12.10 and have NOT updated.

After the last update on about March 26th I started getting `usr/share/apport/apport-gpu-error-intel.py` errors.

Reinstalled and updated same thing, so now I'm not updating and have no issues.

I am running a Lenovo G570 with Intel I3 and 2000 graphics.

How can I find out when this bug has been repaired and know I can start to update 12.10 again?

Comment: Could you mention the **complete** output of the error? Also, you should say **when** it appears**.

Comment: No I can't unfortunately I did not record the information.

Answer (score 0):

Same problem from Lenovo ThinkCentreEdge.
For my case, after the update, desktop background had lines on it but after I wiped my mouse they disappeared and back to normal. Moreover, my computer was working a lot slower and often hanged so need to reboot.
My solution is same as Diogenes, re-install Ubuntu and avoid updating.